# Image from resources won't load on Android using QML (QT)

Tags: android, qt, qml

Seems like basic stuff:

1) there's an image defined within an RCC file

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file alias="image.png">images/image.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

2) the image is referenced within a QML file

```
Image {
            source:  "images/image.png"
        }
```

The image is recognized and displayed fine within the QT Creator's GUI einvoronment. BUT, when deployed to android there's a runtime error from .SO

```
armeabi-v7a.so: qrc:/main.qml:76:9: QML Image: Cannot open: qrc:/images/image.png
```

Now considering I wanted to do this the 'proper' way i.e. rely on QT's multi-platform capabilities and resource management and *do not* do any hacky stuff by tinkering with android folder, what is the proper way?

Also, if QT  attempts to introduce a multi-platform resource-abstraction layer over each platform; how does it handle various resolutions? For instance, in Android there's typically a separate folder for each DPI range. Does it do any kind of automatic scaling / conversions? (obviously not but then how to provide these various bitmaps to QT). It's related.

Comment: If you are talking about icons, have a look at [Icon Themes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-icons.html#icon-themes). If not icons, did you try `"qrc:/images/image.png"`? (I know it seems weird, but this way is what I currently have for a working android app)

Comment: "qrc:/images/image.png" was not recognized by either QT Creator or Android i.e. it did not even render within Creator's GUI

Comment: I got tired of trying to do this the 'right way', seem's like the QT's resource management is utterly broken and not finished. i.e. I tried setting the image through Creators GUI which showed the image available on a drop down-list from resources and produced "source: "images/image.png" within QML file. NOW.. that did NOT work on Android also.. so.. it's broken. What I did was the obvious way of creating separate images in corresponding DPI folders  and setting source: "./image.png" but that's entirely platform dependent . right?

Answer (score 0):

These issues is related URL on device's environment.
So you should link URL on the code.
Try like the below:

```
Image { source:  "qrc:/images/image.png"}
```

Comment: read my post  (especially the bottom lines) *and* the comments (tried that).